# Error 400 - Bad Request to Service Now API using win_uri module

Tags: rest, ansible, uri, servicenow

I'm working on an automation whose last step is to update a ticket in service now. To do this, I am attempting to use the [ansible.builtin.win_uri](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) module to send a PATCH request to the incident indicated in the URL. The problem is, no matter how I format my body, I always get a 400 bad request error and I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting this as I am learning ansible on the fly.

I can see I'm logged in from the headers in the failure message:
"x_is_logged_in": "true",

My task currently:

```
    - name: Update Ticket
      register: RESULT_update_ticket
      ansible.builtin.win_uri:
        url: "https://<ORG>.service-now.com/api/<HEADER>_<ORG>_rest/<ORG>_incident/{{ incident_number }}"
        url_method: PATCH
        return_content: true
        content_type: application/json
        force_basic_auth: true
        headers:
          Accept: application/json
        validate_certs: false
        url_username: <Account Username>
        url_password: <Account Password>
        body: | 
          {
            "comments" : "Test comment from ansible"
          }
    - debug:
        var: result
```

I suspect my problem is somewhere is in how I'm doing the body but I'm not sure what I need to do or change. but essentially I'm trying to send JSON a REST API

Comment: (a) have you tried the normal `uri:` flavor to see if it behaves the same way? Your request doesn't seem to be windows-specific (b) what is in the 400 response body? (c) are you sure you wouldn't be happier using [one of the supported modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/collections/servicenow/servicenow/index.html)?

Comment: Hey @mdaniel thanks for getting back to me. (A) My understanding is the difference between uri/win_uri is the target platform. Uri is for linue and win_uri is for windows hosts. Since this playbook is running against  windows host I think I'm doing this correctly. (B) this is something I didn't realize to check for and it would seem my orgs internal API developers have changed APIs but not updated documentation :) this call even fail in a previously working postman collection.  (c) god bless you I'm gonna give it a try!